# Spring.queries property in application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a web app that uses Spring Security for authentication and authorization.

In my securityConfiguration file I have these lines

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
private String usersQuery;

@Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
private String rolesQuery;
```

Which are later on used for authentication.
In the application.properties files I have :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql= true

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false


spring.queries.users-query=select email, password from users where email=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role from users u inner join 
user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r 
on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?
```

But I get : 'spring.datasource.testWhileIdle' is an unknown property. Did you mean 'spring.datasource.tomcat.abandon-when-percentage-full'?
and also an error about spring.validationQuery as well as spring.queries..it's underlined yellow.
So the login process always return false.

Could anyone help me figure out where the problem is ? I am new with the Spring framework and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a connection pool database please change

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

to this:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

You can see additional information about this in [Spring Documentation - Working with Database.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database)

Also change `spring.queries.users-query` and `spring.queries.roles-query` to `myapp.queries.users-query` and `myapp.queries.roles-query` respectively.  All the properties that start with `spring.*` are standard properties, all the available standard properties  are listed in [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).  If you need to use  custom properties change the name  for example using `myapp.mycustomproperty`

Comment: After changing the code accordingly, it does not validate the credentials as needed. So when I login it redirects me to the error landing login page.
The db that I'm using is mysql in Amazon , so i have spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://test....amazonaws.com:3306/test. Could that be an issue ? The tutorial I'm following is https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d. Thank you once again!

Comment: According to the tutorial you have to change `users-query=select email, password from users where email=?` to this `select email, password, active from users where email=?`  and the 'role-query` you have to change  the table user name to `user` without the `s`, of course it will depends on how you define the entities name.  You can also put a stack trace or  the error that you get into the question get a more clear view of the  problem

Comment: Thank you once again. It's users because that's how my table is named. And I did add the active field, But the thing is, there is no error shown.
If the email and password I'm entering in the login site is correct and its role is ADMIN, I should get redirected to another file if not, should get redirected to login?error=true. But even when all of that is correct, I get redirected to login?error=true. Cuz the registration works. And that's what I can't seem figure out.

Comment: Could be because the tutorial is using `.passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);` that means it will depends how the password is stored on your database.  Try removing the `.passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);` if it works then it is because the password is not saved encoded, that means that  is saved as plain text.

Comment: The password is stored using the same method; because saved it using the registration with Spring Security. But even when removing that and adding an ADMIN user with plain text password it still doesn't log in. Also the myapp.queries.users-query' is an unknown property. Should I create metadata for it ? Could that be the issue? But when the query was wrong it did tell me. So I'm not sure. Nevertheless, thank you for your time and help, I do not want to disturb you if you don't have time

Comment: we can discuss in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152945/spring-queries-property-in-application-properties

Comment: ..I don't have reputation ahhh

Comment: Also you could try downloading the entire  source code  from git hub and compare it with your code, actually I downloaded and runs ok, of course setting the proper values to the db  configuration and running  the database creation before https://github.com/gustavoponce7/SpringSecurityLoginTutorial

Comment: thank you! No it isn't solved yet, I was trying to get reputation scores so I could use the chat.
That's why I dont know why it wouldn't work.
I used the same exact code, except for the db configuration.
But I'll try and create the db again before trying it and will let you know!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152969/discussion-between-flor-a-and-daniel-c).